# Find all n-digit strictly increasing numbers using c++

Tags: c++, recursion

**[Problem Statement](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-n-digit-strictly-increasing-numbers-bottom-top-approach/):**
To generate the n-digit numbers which will be in strictly increasing order.

**for example:**

**8–digit strictly increasing numbers are:**

---

```
12345678 12345679 12345689 12345789 12346789 12356789 12456789 13456789 23456789
```

I am trying to use recursion to create n digit strictly increasing numbers. But I ain't getting the expected output. I am confused what went wrong. why I am getting 6 digits instead of 3 and they are also not strictly increasing.

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:

void gen_num(int prev, string ans, int n, int ind){

    if (n==ind){
            cout<<ans<< " ";
        return;
    }

    for (int i=1+prev; i<=9; i++){
        gen_num(i, ans+to_string(i+'0'), n, ind+1);
    }

}

};


int main()
{
    Solution sol;
    int n=3;
    sol.gen_num(0,"", n, 0);

}
```

---

### Update:

Got it the issue was with `ans+to_string(i+'0')` should be `ans+to_string(i)`

Comment: why would you use recursion for this ? can you also explain more clearly what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code to see when and where things start to go wrong?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Using debugger for recursion( stack concept based thing) will make the things complicated for me to understand the recursion. logic seems okay to me but I Can't seem to find what's causing this.

Comment: @Louis-JustinTallot: I have edited the post. I am trying to solve every question using recursion for learning purpose.

Comment: thank you, we can now understand the problem :) please see my answer

Comment: Think about what the number you end up passing to `to_string` is If `'0'` is 48.

Comment: Understanding the logic of code is what debuggers are for. You step (advance the program roughly line by line) and observe the path taken by the program and the changes the line made to the program's state (the variables). The alternative is todo the same thing on paper with a pen or pencil. Using the debugger is less error prone.as if you are wrong about how a line of code should be interpreted , the bad assumption will follow through into your pen and paper exploration. The debugger will not be as kind. It shows exactly what you told the computer to do, no matter your actual intent.

Comment: @Pygirl if it works for you, please accept my answer :)

Comment: @user4581301: I will follow your advice next time I will use debugger. Need to learn how to use it inside the code blocks ide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By removing `+'0'` in your code I already have something that works better (see [here](http://cpp.sh/5cduj) to test it online):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
// #include <string_view>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:

void gen_num(int prev, string ans, int n, int ind){
    // cout<<prev<<" "<<n<<" "<<ind<<endl;
    if (n==ind){
            cout<<ans<< " ";
        return;
    }

    for (int i=1+prev; i<=9; i++){
        gen_num(i, ans+to_string(i), n, ind+1);
    }
}
};


int main() {
    Solution sol;
    int n=3;
    sol.gen_num(0,"", n, 0);

}
```

and the output :

123 124 125 126 127 128 129 134 135 136 137 138 139 145 146 147 148 149 156 157 158 159 167 168 169 178 179 189 234 235 236 237 238 239 245 246 247 248 249 256 257 258 259 267 268 269 278 279 289 345 346 347 348 349 356 357 358 359 367 368 369 378 379 389 456 457 458 459 467 468 469 478 479 489 567 568 569 578 579 589 678 679 689 789

which seems to be the 3-digit strictly increasing numbers.

See Hanjoung Lee's answer below or an explanation of the phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>        gen_num(i, ans+to_string(i+'0'), n, ind+1);
> ```

I think you actually meant here `ans+(char)(i+'0')` or `ans+to_string(i)`.

`ans+(i+'0')` does not work since `i+'0'` is an int not a char.

Comment: Yeah this conversion to `char`  and `int` part was not clear to me. How c++ is doing all this so I just messed the thing here.

Comment: can you tell what's the difference between `i+'0'` and `i-'0'`?

Comment: '0' is in fact equal to the integer value 48 (see [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) so `i+'0'` is `i+48` and `i-'0'` is `i-48`

Comment: Exactly as @Louis-JustinTallot said. And for both, the result is type of int.

Comment: @Louis-JustinTallot oh got it 0 will get map to integer and then normal addition subtraction thing will happen.

Comment: In practice(when need some quick string/int conversion) `i+'0'` is for converting an integral type to char(ascii code). `i-'0'` for char to an integral type.

Comment: And when you perform int + char, char is promoted as int, AFAIK